# Storing pwr.t.test value in dplyr summary statistics

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to store the **n value** from the pwr.t.test in my FWD_SummaryStats df but each time I run the code I crash R.  The exact error code is "*This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way...*"

I'm not sure why it's happening, as running each statistics separately produces the correct result.  Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

```
FWD_SummaryStats<-summarize(FWD1, count = n(), min = min(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    mean = mean(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), median = median(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    max = max(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), varience = var(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    SD = sd(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T),
                    n = pwr.t.test(d=((1.15*mean)-mean)/SD, sig.level=0.05,power = 0.95,type= "one.sample",alternative = "two.sided")$n
)
```

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: can you include sample data?

Comment: That does not look like an R crash report. Are you using something other than CRAN delivered version of R?

Comment: @42 Nope, it's the official version.  It's quite odd for the summarize function to crash when all of those metrics work fine when calculated individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has this issue, the problem lies in this line:

```
n = pwr.t.test(d=((1.15*mean)-mean)/SD, sig.level=0.05, power = 0.95,type="one.sample", alternative = "two.sided")$'n'
```

The $n must be surrounded by quotations to form $'n' in order to store the value.

```
SummaryStatistics<- 
          summarize(FWD1, count = n(), min = min(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    mean = mean(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), median = median(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    max = max(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), varience = var(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T), 
                    SD = sd(FWD_1_Fuel_Load, na.rm = T),
                    n = pwr.t.test(d=((1.15*mean)-mean)/SD, sig.level=0.05, power = 0.95,type="one.sample", alternative = "two.sided")$'n'
)
```

I hope this helps those who were stuck on the same issue.

Kev

Comment: If you really can crash CRAN R, then you should submit a bug report by emailing the package author and the r-devel mailing list.